# Parse time with microseconds in Java

Tags: java

I am having problems parsing time strings in Java that are in the format of `2013-01-09 09:15:03.000000`. In my data, the last three digits are always 0 (meaning the input strings have only millisecond precision), so I passed this format to SimpleDateFormat:

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'000'");
```

but `formatter.parse("2013-01-09 09:15:02.500000");` throws an exception:

```
Unparseable date: "2013-01-09 09:15:02.500000"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
```

Anyone knows how to do it correctly?  I can work around by using format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` and using `substring` to get rid of last three digits but that's really hacky.

EDIT: can anyone explain why the format string `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'000'` can't be used to parse time `"2013-01-09 09:15:02.500000"`

Comment: The biggest issues that I can see is the fact that the parser doesn't care about the number of digits that appear (per say), so you could `.S` and it would parse `5`, `500` or `500000`, but this would introduce rolling of the time value to compensate...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, does mean if I pass in a string `"2013-01-09 09:15:02.5`, it will parse it as 5 milliseconds instead of 500?  That's really stupid.

Comment: Perhaps it is, but what it does make it is a flexible, so you could also pass it `2013-1-9 9:15:2.500` and it would work.  The way the parse works and the way that the formatter works are slightly different...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out myself.  Just FYI, Apache commons' `FastDateFormat` seems accepting the `SSS000` format and parses the time correctly.

Answer (score 3):

try java.sql.Timestamp

```
     Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2013-01-09 09:15:03.500000"); 
     Date date = new Date(ts.getTime())
```

it's also thread-safe and fast as opposed to SimpleDateFormat

Comment: I forgot to mention, the time string actually is not in UTC time zone but some local time zone.  I want to be able to set the time zone and convert to UTC.  SimpleDateFormat can set timezone but Timestamp can't.

Comment: Timestamp parses input in local time zone, try String s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(ts.getTime());
and you will get the same time

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

I should like to contribute the modern answer. Use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. One option, you may use a formatter:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(timeString, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

When using the string from your question, `"2013-01-09 09:15:02.500000"`, this printed:

```
2013-01-09T09:15:02.500
```

If you want the value printed with six decimals on the seconds even when the last three decimals are 0, use the same formatter to format the time back into a string:

```
    System.out.println(dateTime.format(formatter));
```

The other option, you may exploit the fact that your string resembles the ISO 8601 format, the format that the modern classes parse as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter. Only ISO 8601 has a `T` to denote the start of the time part, but we can fix that easily:

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(timeString.replace(' ', 'T'));
```

It gives the same result, `2013-01-09T09:15:02.500`. It’s shorter, but also more tricky.

### Why bother?

The classes `Date` and `Timestamp` are long outdated, and `SimpleDateFormat` in particular has proven troublesome. Its surprising behaviour in your situation is just one little story out of very many. The modern API is generally so much nicer to work with.

### Why didn’t your formatter work?

While the format pattern strings used by `SimpleDateFormat` and `DateTimeFormatter` are similar, there are differences. One is that `SimpleDateFormat` understands uppercase `S` as milliseconds no matter of there are one or nine of them, whereas to `DateTimeFormatter` they mean fraction of second. Your `SimpleDateFormat` furthermore grabbed all six digits after the decimal point, ignoring the fact that you had typed only three `S`, so there were no zeroes left to match the `'000'` (by the way, the apostrophes are not necessary, only letters need them).

### Link

[Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)