# Calendars getTime method modifies the timezone

Tags: java, date, timezone, timezone-offset, java.util.calendar

I have a problem whereby the Calendar.getTime() method changes the timezone (probably to be in line with the JVM).

```
Calendar cal  = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2017-10-20T07:10:08.123458Z");
Date datrFromCal = cal.getTime();//Adds two hours(GMT+2:00)
```

Is there any way to stop this movement from GMT+0 to GMT+2 when calling `cal.getTime()`?

P.s. We use Java 7 at my company.

Another thing related to this is the support for microseconds. I have read a lot about Java 7 and below not supporting microSeconds (when parsing a String), but is there any suggestions to get around this?

Comment: Java 7 answer to both your questions: Get [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and use the modern Java date and time API. It gives you close control over timezone and offset, and it has straightforward support for microseconds. Plus, it is much nicer to work with in general.

Comment: Hi Ole. From the link you sent it indeed looks like I created a duplicate with regards to the timezone part to my question. :(

Comment: @ChristopherBarrett Your Question is also a duplicate of other topics, including [parsing microseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952618/parse-time-with-microseconds-in-java). Search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting; you can assume most basic date-time questions have already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the `Date` that has the timezone. Dates are simply a number of milliseconds since the "epoch" (1 Jan 1970 GMT). They do not contain timezone information. You only see time zones when you format a date for display. By default, it uses the timezone for your locale. You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to print a date with a different `Locale` or `TimeZone`.

Make sure your `Calendar` instance has the right `TimeZone` (e.g. you might have to explicitly set it: `cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));`).

If I were you, I'd switch to the [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)  time library or the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and use the far better designed `java.time`. The built-in java.util.Date/Calendar classes are a nightmare to work with. They are poorly designed and *mutable*, which means you can't trust them as value objects to be passed around.

Comment: The answer is correct. I concur, do switch to a more modern date and time API. Now you’re at it, why not pick `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API developed by the folks behind Joda-Time? Joda-Time is in maintenance mode, a finished project, so `java.time` seems the future-proof option.

Comment: Thanks Ole. I didn't know there was a backport. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Trusting that the parsing is correct, the `Z` in the string should make sure that the `Calendar` has UTC (AKA Zulu) time zone, AKA zero offset. I still agree completely, avoid using that class and move on to `java.time` through the backport.

Answer (score 0):

Though i agree with @ELEVATE, i have to add that the iso 8601 date format uses a time zone.

We can see that you are effectively setting the timezone with the 'Z' indicator but not specify it. Therefore, the calendar is built using the your local time zone but with the time defined as UTC (or GMT if you prefer, therefore as GMT+2h00 in your case).

If, however, you remove the 'Z' indicator, you'll the time set with your timezone as it is.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators for instance

Comment: It depends on the desired time zone. My guess is that the `Z` is there exactly because the OP wants offset 0 from UTC. The OP can best tell. Otherwise you are completely correct.